# routeParams doesnt inject into my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I was looking at some how-tos on doing angular-routing and to pass parameters into a controller.  This is what i did:

```
.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$routeParams", function($scope, $routeParams, Units, Tests){
  //Units and Tests are both factories i created to reference within this function.
  var id = $routeParams.id;
  console.log(id);
}]);
```

When I did this, it failed to inject "$routeParams" into my application.

I looked at the angular.js file, and it looks like i am running: *@license AngularJS v1.5.3*

Is this way of doing it no longer the correct way?  I tried to update it to:

```
.controller("myController", ["$scope", "ngRoute", function($scope, ngRoute, Units, Tests){
  // ...
}]);
```

but that seemed to also not inject correctly.

Is there something I am missing?

Currently I am developing with the Ionic Framework, which is leveraging the AngularJS tools.

Comment: `"ngRoute"` goes into your app module call, ie `angular.module("app",["ngRoute"])`, did you include it?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the app when this controller is in scope?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I got this error: *Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.*

Comment: @Fallenreaper You have to either import it from a CDN or install it with your package manager of choice (npm, bower, etc)

Comment: ngRoute is a separate module file, you have to include `angular.route.js` or the minified version

Comment: Is there a way to do this within Ionic?  I am using that framework.  im looking through their api, and im sure they have this in place already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with ionic, as stated within the question, you connect to the `$stateProvider` so when you are creating a state such as:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("unit", {
    url: "/unit/:id",
    templateUrl: "templates/unit.html",
    controller: "UnitController"
  })
```

you would then in your controller do:

```
.controller("myController", ["$scope", 
    "$stateParams", 
    function($scope, $stateParams, Units, Tests){
  var id = $stateParams.id;
  console.log(id);
}]);
```

This is the way to do it in Ionic, since it is leveraging a `$stateProvider` over a `$routeProvider`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to different pages in your application, but you also want the application to be a `SPA (Single Page Application)`, with no page reloading, you can use the `ngRoute` module.

The ngRoute module routes your application to different pages without reloading the entire application.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.html"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.html"
    });
});
```

Your application needs a container to put the content provided by the routing.

This container is the `ng-view directive`.

like this

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

You can also define controllers for each view

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
    .when("/london", {
        templateUrl : "test.html",
        controller : "myController"
    })

});
```

Comment: Can you show me a working sample with routeParams, as asked in the quesetion.  Maybe:  */blue/:id" for example, and then get the parameter within the controller definition.